# How to move array with days of week one item backwards js

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays

```
const weekDays = [
  { label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' },
  { label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' },
  { label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' },
  { label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' },
  { label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },
  { label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },
  { label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' },
];
```

and `const daysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri']`

What I wanted to achieve is to move array(daysOfWeek) one item backwards, that is, `daysOfWeek = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu']`.

To achieve that I created such code

```
const selectedDaysOfWeek = weekDays.map(({label, name}, index, array) => {
   if (daysOfWeek.includes(label)) {
       return array[index - 1].label;
   }
   return ''
});
```

but it returns label of undefined.

Comment: so, all you need is just a "carousel" for array elements?  
```js
daysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
daysOfWeek.unshift(daysOfWeek.pop())
console.log(daysOfWeek) // ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
```
or for another direction:  
```js
daysOfWeek.push(daysOfWeek.shift()) // ['Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon']
```
Is it for are you looking for?

Comment: @Xeelley, hey)) I just wanted dynamic solution))

Comment: @Xeelley, I mean, even if I have ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'] or ['Thu', 'Fri'] I could move each item backwards by one DYNAMICALLY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your solution is:

```js
const weekDays = [
    { label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' },
    { label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' },
    { label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' },
    { label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' },
    { label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },
    { label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },
    { label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' },
];
let daysOfWeek = ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'] 

const firstDayIndex = weekDays.findIndex(day => day.label === daysOfWeek[0]) // get current day index
daysOfWeek.unshift(weekDays[(firstDayIndex || weekDays.length) - 1].label) // add previous day by index
daysOfWeek.pop() // remove last day
console.log(daysOfWeek) // // ['Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu'], here we go
```

Comment: thank you ))) but if array starts from 'Mon', I think it will also work right? like let daysOfWeek = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed'] since index of Mon is 0 and we do index - 1 and that showed error for me))

Comment: @qweeee it will, 'cause of `weekDays[(firstDayIndex || weekDays.length) - 1]` - it takes length if `firstDaysIndex` is zero and jumps to last element instead of "minus first" :) Check it out!

Comment: I tried your solution and works a bit incorrect. If I have ['Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri'] then I get ["Sun", "Mon", "Wed"] but should be ["Sun", "Tue", "Thu"]

Comment: @qweeee you right, maybe I missed something in your question, so can you explain once more time why it should be `["Sun", "Tue", "Thu"]` skipping `"Mon"`?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `Array.prototype.pop()` to remove the element from the end and return that element, then use `Array.prototype.unshift()` to insert an element to the beginning

```js
const weekDays = [
    { label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' },
    { label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' },
    { label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' },
    { label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' },
    { label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },
    { label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },
    { label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' },
];

const lastElement = weekDays.pop(); // get last element
weekDays.unshift(lastElement); // get new array that last element is first one 
let finalResult = weekDays.map(x => x.label) // get only names of week days from object
console.log(finalResult)
```

**EDIT**: according to the OP's needs

```js
const weekDays = [
    { label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' },
    { label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' },
    { label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' },
    { label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' },
    { label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },
    { label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },
    { label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' },
];

function getWeeks(arr) {
    return [arr[arr.length - 1], ...arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1)];
}

console.log(getWeeks(['Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu']));
console.log(getWeeks(weekDays));
```

Comment: hey)), thank you for your answer, but is it possible to achieve that by accessing the previous label therefore I used array[index - 1].label. I JUST WANTED DYNAMIC SOLUTION))

Comment: hmm one second .

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic ?

Comment: @DostonbekOripjonov, hey)) I mean imagine you can have array(daysOfWeek) with any length, you know, it can be ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'] or ['Wed', 'Thu'] or just ['Fri']. So, whatever the length of the array(daysOfWeek, I wanted to get the previous day of the week, for example, ['Wed', 'Thu'] transform it into ['Tue', 'Wed'] or transform ['Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'] into ['Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu'] . I hope you got my point))

Comment: Oo yea ill edit my answer when i get back home

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = [weekDays[weekDays.length-1],...weekDays.slice(0,weekDays.length-1)].slice(0,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `map`:

```js
const weekDays = [
    { label: 'Mon', name: 'Monday' },
    { label: 'Tue', name: 'Tuesday' },
    { label: 'Wed', name: 'Wednesday' },
    { label: 'Thu', name: 'Thursday' },
    { label: 'Fri', name: 'Friday' },
    { label: 'Sat', name: 'Saturday' },
    { label: 'Sun', name: 'Sunday' },
];
let c = weekDays.map((i, x, s) => typeof s[x - 1] === "undefined" ? s[s.length - 1].label : s[x - 1].label)

console.log(c);
```